# Cartthrob PHP Error when checking out

Tags: matrix, cartthrob, publisher

I have an issue with Cartthrob. When checking out, everything seems to be working ok. An email is fired, order entry created, but I am not returned to confirm page. I am using offsite payments.

The issue seems to be when creating an entry in the order entry and the fieldtype that is responsible with posting that.

Other things to note:
CT v2.5
EE v2.7
I'm using Publisher by BoldedMinds
Matrix for pricing options with CT

Anyone had this issue?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: cartthrob_order_items/ft.cartthrob_order_items.php

Line Number: 80

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at     /Volumes/Sites/www.domain.dev/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at     /Volumes/Sites/www.domain.dev/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Volumes/Sites/www.domain.dev/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Volumes/Sites/www.domain.dev/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 414
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling Publisher to see if the same error still occurs? Always remove things from the equation first to see if the error resolves itself, and if it does then you know what add-on might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Having reviewed the problem and the relevant code, it appears that the data that's

Because the configuration is fairly complex I suggest you schedule a Phone/Skype appointment with the CartThrob/Mightybigrobot support team at http://support.mightybigrobot.com. A member of our support team can speak with your personally and will custom tailor a suitable solution to this issue.

In the order items field_type you could find:

```
        foreach ($data as $i => $row)
```

around line 80 and change it to:

```
        if (!is_array($data) || empty($data))
    {
        $this->EE->load->remove_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'cartthrob/');
        return $data;
    }
    foreach ($data as $i => $row)
```

But I think what you'll find then is that order items aren't being created for some reason. Normally we'd expect order items to be created during the checkout process (if items exist in the cart), but I'm guessing here that for some reason the items aren't being created, or no data is being passed to the pre_processor (which is in the field type)

If we can have a call, one of us can take a look at your specific setup and nail down the issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Mine is fired when I change the status for the order in CT Admin. Working on EE 2.7 with publisher. Latest version of CT. Any chance for an update on this issue?