# Cartthrob packing slip template doesn't display channel fields

Tags: cartthrob, publisher

Here's a simplified version of my packing slip template code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="orders" limit="1" status="open|New|Shipped" dynamic="no" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

<h1>{title}</h1> <!-- Shows order number OK -->

<p><strong>Ship to:</strong> {order_shipping_first_name} {order_shipping_first_name}</p> <!-- Shows nothing -->

{exp:cartthrob:order_items order_id="{entry_id}"}

<p>{item:title} {item:price} {item:quantity} {item:subtotal}</p> <!-- Order items display OK, but I get a PHP warning -->

{/exp:cartthrob:order_items}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I replace {entry_id} with an actual order entry_id and view the template outside of the control panel, it displays everything just fine:

[image]

However, if I set it as the packing slip template in the CT system settings and click 'Print packing slip', it brings up the template OK, but won't display anything other than the {title} tag from the orders channel and throws a PHP warning when displaying the order items:

[image]

Am I using the wrong template tags, or is this a bug in Cartthrob?

Right - I've now installed the example CT templates and tried to use that and... It still doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: How are you passing in the {entry_id} in the first channel entries tag? maybe you should pass the entry_id in through segments because as a parameter entry_id="{entry_id}", should not work.

Comment: I'm doing it how the CT docs tell me to do it: http://cartthrob.com/docs/docs_cartthrob-order-manager/#features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aargh! The issue was with boldminded's [Publisher](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher) module.

Not sure what the problem is, but if I disable that, the fields come through onto the packing slip no problem at all. Now I just need to see if upgrading Publisher to 1.2.2 makes a difference.

I wish these expensive CT add-ons would play together a bit better :-/

Comment: Publisher 1.2.2 makes no difference. Closing this question anyway now as the issue isn't with CartThrob. Adding 'Publisher' to the tags though...

Answer (score 1):

I'd check that your actually passing the entry_id correctly. But i'd also make sure your not disabling anything on the channel entries loop with the disable="" parameter.

If in doubt, try adding dynamic="no" as well ;)

Comment: I'm not disabling anything, plus I am using 'dynamic="no"' (have updated my template code to reflect this).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the same problem as here: [Cartthrob PHP Error when checking out](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/cartthrob-php-error-when-checking-out). Perhaps Chris Newton's suggested fix would solve the problem for now.